# connecting to a database in visual studio for membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, forms-authentication

I have a website that I created.  In the Appdata folder I created a database (info.mdf).

I connected it to SQLEXpress

I have added NETWORK SERVICE to available users in SQL mngmnt studio.   I went to user mapping and added my database.   I selected  the db_owner, public and aspnet_Membership_FullAccess.  I did the same process with my local username but I guess because of the way I setup my database the local user shows up as dbo under the users in the actual database.

I altered my web.config to say:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MembershipConnection" connectionString="Server=machinename\SQLEXPRESS;  Initial Catalog=Info;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>


    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="1720">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="SqlProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
           connectionStringName="MembershipConnection"
           enablePasswordReset="true"
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
           requiresUniqueEmail="false"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
           passwordAttemptWindow="30"
           minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
           applicationName="/" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled ="true" />

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tried  Trusted_Connection=Yes in the connection string as well as Integrated Security=SSPI

The error I get is:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Info" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MachineName\username'.]

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx

This link says that in order to do windows authentication, you must have

```
Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

or

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

in the connection string.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I will edit, I Forgot to mention that I tried both of those with the same result

Comment: May I ask how you created the database?

Comment: And, are the credentials that you are using in your project the same as the ones you are using in management studio?

Comment: I created the database through visual studio 2010.  I added it to the App_data folder, then selected attach through management studio. And yes the credentials are the same.  I assume I don't have to supply a password in web.config?

Comment: this connection string works ---> "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Info.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />  Any idea why it doesn't work when I don't reference the mdf?

Comment: I do not understand why, but it seems this reference suggests it has to be that way for mdf's in the app_data folder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  It also looks specific to sql express as opposed to full versions